# How many number of classes over matrices with $\pm 1$ entries are there, where equivalence means row/column permutation and multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, group-theory, permutations

I'm interested in the number of inequivalent matrices with $\pm 1$ entries, where equivalence means row permutation, column permutation, row multiplication with $-1$, and column multiplication with $-1$?

If $\sim$ is the equivalence relation on $n \times m$ binary matrices such that $A \sim B$ iff one can obtain $B$ by applying any combination of the above operations (row/column permutation, row/column multiplication with $-1$) to $A$, I'm interested in the number of $\sim$-equivalence classes over all $n \times m$ matrices with $\pm 1$ entries. Thank you.

Comment: When you write row/column permutation, you mean both at the same time like $P^{-1}AP$ or does a single operation suffice, like $AP$ (where $P$ is your permutation matrix)?$

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I use a slash to save space. It means a single operation "row permutation or column permutation" (like $AP$, but not necessarily $P^{-1}AP$ at the same time). The same applies for row/column multiplication.

Comment: I've updated the description in the problem.

Comment: Calculate it for some small values of $m$ and $n$, and then look it up in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: [This paper](http://coding.yonsei.ac.kr/pdf/journal_reprint/43.pdf) shows some small results, but OEIS doesn't contain the sequence.

Comment: I am not sure ifI undeerstadn the question. Whta